# Deep linking opening both installed app on the android and playstore url

Tags: javascript, android, deep-linking

I am trying to acheive deeplinking through below javascrip piece of code, but the issue is if I have an installed app on android device it is opening both application and playstore url at sametime.Any suggestions to this?

```
<html>

<body>
<button onclick="launchAndroidApp()">Deep linking test</button>
<script>
function launchAndroidApp() {
            var test = window.open('DeeplinkingURL', "_self"); 
            setTimeout("window.location = 'Playstoreurl", 1000);
    }
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single URL using [Android Intents with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents). For example, supposing `DeeplinkingUrl="https://example.com/hello"` and you expect it to be opened by the `com.example.Hello` application,

```
intent://example.com/hello
    #Intent;
    scheme=https;
    package=com.example.Hello;
    S.browser_fallback_url=market%3A%2F%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.example.Hello;
    end
```

without the spaces, will use `com.example.Hello` to launch `https://example.com/hello` if available, and open the Play store listing for the app otherwise. (Of course you could use `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=` instead of `market://details?id=`.)

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` method simply gets executed regardless after 1 second. This is not the right approach to doing so, but if you are convinced on this method, I'd try using a try-catch.

```
try{
  window.open('DeeplinkingURL', "_self");
} catch {
  window.location = 'Playstoreurl';
}
```

Instead, I'd recommend using [Branch](http://branch.io). You can do this with their SDK for free and much cleaner.